# Spring MVC submit only one element of render List in page

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I have been looking for this answer here and in google without any success. I will explain what I´m looking for and let´s see if someone can help me.

Using Spring MCV I´m rendering a List of A objects "aList" into my view.JSP.

```
    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public final ModelAndView getAList(){
        ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView("view");
        List<A> aList = new ArrayList<>();
        aList.add(new A("a1");
        aList.add(new A("a2");
        mav.addObject("aList", aList);
        return mav;
    }
```

Where A looks like

```
  public class A{
      @Getter
      @Setter
      private String value; 
      public A(String value){
             this.value=value;
       }
    }
```

For every iteration of the list I´m creating a form. The form looks like

```
  <c:forEach var="a" items="${aList}"
               varStatus="status">

      <form:form id="A${a.id}"
               method="post" action="save.do"
               modelAttribute="a">

               <input type="submit"  value="Save"/>
      </form:form>
  </c:forEach>
```

so after finish the render I have so many forms as objects in my list.
Every form as you can imagine has his submit button. 
Now what I´m trying to do without any success is to send one of this form to my controller, but not the whole list of A that I render but A. So my controller will look something like.

```
   RequestMapping(value = "/save", method = RequestMethod.POST)
         public final ModelAndView save(@ModelAttribute("a") A a) {
```

But I´m receiving a "IllegalStateException: Neither BindingResult nor plain target object for bean name" because the render name of my modelAndView "aList" is not the same than "a".

What I think I understand is that Spring MVC components like form dont allow submit a different class that was used in the render. Even if is a nested class of the render class, what is too bad.

I would like to avoid have to send the aList again.

Any idea?

Regards.

Comment: "because the render name of my modelAndView "aList" is not the same than "a"" that doesn't make sense, the problem is spring can't convert the form to A. Can you get just one form to work ? Is aList definitely a's, there are no other element sin your form ?

Comment: the idea like I say is has so many forms as list elements. Is a functional request so I cannot change that. The only solution that I achieve make works is to submit in every subform the list with just the element of that subform, but is not elegant at all!. I cannot believe that Spring dont have amechanism for this. Is pretty common feature. in every CMS

Comment: Show the bean A, has a list in it doesn't it ?

Comment: example public class A{ private String bla;}  What I want is send separately every A in a independent form in my view

Comment: edit your question to show A and the definition of aList

Comment: I edit my question, no idea how to fix it?

Comment: @NimChimpsky: as A contains a single String, could my proposal of using a `@RequestParam` **with the name of that field** be of any use ? (becoming prudent :-) because it will never be a general solution)

Comment: Could you present what is the HTML generated by Spring for one of your forms ? Could lead to an idea of how to tell Spring that you want a single A or an explaination of why it doesn't want ...

Comment: What is `a.id` from the `A` class? You aren't showing anything relevant in the question

Comment: Guys, all this it´s just an example, try please to extrapolate this A object to a complex object structure.

Comment: @paul there's your problem, have you got this working with one complex object ? We can't extrapolate - as it should work as is.

Comment: Would do you mean by *submit in every subform the list with just the element of that subform* could you give an example of a field of your form other than the `<input type="submit"  value="Save"/>`

Comment: As long as you won't tell how you do the render part with at least `a.value`, I couldn't help you to do the submit part.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of attempting to post back the entire contents of the selected element,
consider posting back an identifier for the selected element.
For example:

```
<form:form method="post" action="save.do">
    <c:forEach items="${aList}"
               var="element"
               varStatus="status">

    <input type="submit"
           name="selectedElementId"
           value="${element.id}"/>
    </c:forEach>
</form:form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, it works. The problem if that the `<form:xxx>` elements (eg `<form:input>`) have a problem with a path that starts with an element which is not in the model **in the render part**.

So I slightly modified the exemple given. Here is the form part :

```
<ul><c:forEach var="a" items="${aList}" varStatus="status">
  <li><form:form modelAttribute="a" action="save.do" method="POST" >
    <input type="hidden"  name ="index" value="${status.index}">
    <input type="text"  name ="value" value="${a.value}">
    <input type="submit"  value="Save"/>
  </form:form></li>
</c:forEach></ul>
```

The `<li>` are only for minimal formatting, but the important part is the use of direct `<input>` elements so that Spring MVC don't choke on `a` not being part of the model. So the rendering works.

Now for the save part :

```
RequestMapping(value = "/save", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public final String save(@ModelAttribute("a") A a, @RequestParam("index") int index){
    A aa = aService.getaList().get(index);
    aa.setValue(a.getvalue());
    return "redirect:/list";
}
```

There is no problem, because the name of the model attribute is not present in the POST request. Springs simply creates a new `A` and sets its value attribute. This solution is extensible for complex A classes. The only problem, is that I do not manage errors returned by Spring. They have to be managed at a global level.
(I assumed the URL for the list part was `/list`)

Comment: I tried last Friday that approach not using the Spring form and I could not make it works. The request was arriving to my Controller but without any data. I will try again anyway, thanks

Comment: @paul Could you spy the actual parameters that the request contains ?

Comment: checking the post request with firebug, the structure of the class is send properly but with null attributes.

Comment: @paul Fine, so the problem is still on the render part. Could you update you post with the actual `<form> ...</form>` including `<input>` elements other than the `type=submit` one.

Comment: I´m working right now in another feature, but as soon as I back to this feature I will. Thanks for all your help